# System of ordinary differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I need help to sketch the trajectories in the phase plane for this system of ODE:

$$\begin{array}{|l}
&x'=y  \\
&y'= \beta x-\alpha(1-x^2)y
\end{array}
$$
where $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are positive constants with $x,y \ge 0$.

I already found that the origin is the steady point of the system.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a sketch of the trajectories in the phase plane for $(\alpha,\beta)=(4,3)$, obtained using  [this online tool](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=streamplot%7B%7By%2C3x-4%281-x%5E2%29y%7D%2C%7Bx%2C0%2C2%7D%2C%7By%2C0%2C2%7D%7D):

[image]

Comment: Could you please tell me the code of that ?

Comment: Added a link. $ $

Comment: Anyone want to explain their downvotes?